# How to delete bulk subscribers from All Subscribers List based on a criteria?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I want to delete bulk subscribers from All Subscribers List based on a criteria by using either Automation and Query activity or by using Ampscript...What would be the best way out ?

Comment: What are the criteria exactly? Is it a one-time deletion, or a recurring process?

Comment: Suppose there are some 5000 dummy subscribers having SubscriberKey beginning with Test .... and I want to delete all those test subscribers from the All Subscribers list having 30,000 subscribers..... How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, export the list of All Subscribers into a CSV file and filter the file so that it only has the subscribers you want to delete. Make sure it doesn’t have any subscribers that shouldn’t be deleted, because this cannot be undone.

Next, create a new list in your parent Business Unit and import the subscribers you want to delete into this new list from your csv file.

After double-checking that you only have subscribers that should be deleted on this new list, delete the whole list and make sure to check the box that says `Delete all subscribers in the selected list from the application` - this will permanently delete them from All Subscribers as well.

Bear in mind, that deleting those subscribers from All Subscribers list doesn’t always remove them from Contacts, so you might want to consider using Contact Deletion instead if you’re doing it for the purpose of removing test contacts for billing reasons: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=data_deletion_marketing.htm&type=5&language=en_US